# Visual Studio 2017 with TFS 2013 Build fails

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional and connected it to TFS 2013,i have created build definition and queued a build,but i am getting following error

"C:\Builds\1\Prod\MAIN\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (520): The command """ checkin /override:"Automated" /comment:"***NO_CI*** Automated Build: Updating version number to 1.0.1.0" /noprompt "C:\Builds\1\Prod\MAIN\src\version.txt"" exited with code 9009."
Please help me out i am stuck on this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem,i looked into build script about the paths and changed it according to visual studio 2017 and now i am able to build.